# What does * does in this code of python to get clear output?

Tags: python

These two codes have only one difference in them.
The first one has a `*` in it and the second one dosen't.
The first code runs properly and the second code gives this error:

TypeError: argument should be a string or a Rational instance

Code 1: The correct code.

```
from fractions import Fraction

fracs = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    fracs.append(Fraction(*map(int, input().split())))

print(fracs)
```

Code2 : The errorneous code.

```
from fractions import Fraction

fracs = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    fracs.append(Fraction(map(int, input().split())))

print(fracs)
```

I had learn python from Multiple sites like 'GeeksForGeeks' and 'Tutorial Point'. I checked and they don't tell what does this `*` does apart from being used as a multiplier,string-repeater and passing multiple argument.

Link to the page:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-the-Star-operator-mean-in-Python

Also, searched for this in stackoverrflow's previously asked question but it doesn't give any satisfying result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it passes all the values in the returned tuple as arguments to the function

Comment: `*` here unpacks the arguments. It's the difference between `Fraction([1, 2, 3])` (well, a generator actually, not a list, but that's hard to visualise) and `Fraction(1, 2, 3)`.